# how to combine single dataframe with multiple common columns

Tags: merge, concatenation

There is  single dataframe in pandas and it has 22117 row  and columns 47 but there is common column  13  how to combine these common column single dataframes . how can i solve these problem?
[it is a image single dataframe with multiple common column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhQBM.png)
how to solve these for preprocess datasets